# How to create handler click on text?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

There is a fragment in which I load data from the firebase. The parent directory is called "News". He has a child news1, news2, news (n) .. They contain: imageURL (News picture), news_header (News headline), newsdate (Date news), and also child news_main (Home news) It contains imageURL and news_text. I need to, when I click on the news, opened a new activity and load info about this news in it. That is news_main. I do not use a unique key. Headline news, etc. loaded in recyclerview.

Adapter code:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<News> news;


    public NewsAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<News> n) {
        context = c;
        news = n;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.news_view, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {

        myViewHolder.news_date.setText(news.get(i).getDatenews());
        myViewHolder.news_header.setText(news.get(i).getHeader_news());
        Picasso.get().load(news.get(i).getImageURL()).into(myViewHolder.news_picture);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return news.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView news_date, news_header;
        ImageView news_picture;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            news_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_date);
            news_header = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_header);
            news_picture = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_picture);
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frf8u.png)

```
    list = new ArrayList<News>();

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("News");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                News n = snapshot.getValue(News.class);
                list.add(n);
            }
            adapter = new NewsAdapter(getContext(), list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Что то не так", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please add your database structure and the reference on which you adding the listener.

Comment: Added database struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but what i understood is that you want to call something when you click on a text.

Any view on android have a setOnClickListener(handler) method, you just need to get the reference of the textview and call it

```
news_header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    int position = getAdapterPosition();
    News selected = news.get(position);
    // Do whatever you want with the news
}
```

The code above let you find the reference to the selected item.
You can learn more about it looking for `getAdapterPosition()`

Comment: I need to, when you click on the text of the news, opened a new activity with the main article of this news.

Comment: And sorry for my english)

Comment: I've updated my answer with the corrected info

Answer (score 0):

```
myTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener( your code ));
```

In your code you can insert any function you want to call when your view gets clicked

Comment: I know about this method, I need to transfer the value to the fragment for loading the "main_news"

Comment: Something like that "reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("News").child("main_news")" but it not correctly...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to pass id or anything else to another activity on text click

```
myTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(context,NewActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("id", ""+id);
       context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: I need to add new child in database or i can use as identifier "News1", "News2"

Comment: You should add unique as a child in the database but you can also use "News1", "News2". Just pass those to the new activity and listen to that path in the new activity.